# cannot localize Strings in Flutter tabbar view and list view

Tags: flutter, localization

---

---

When I try to localize a string in a TabBarView I get this error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'translate' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: translate("settingsprofile").

import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:rewahub/views/tabbar.dart';
import 'package:rewahub/widgets/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:rewahub/widgets/styles.dart' ;
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';




class MainHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MainHomePageState createState() => _MainHomePageState();
}

class _MainHomePageState extends State<MainHomePage> {
  final int initialIndex = 1;
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);



  String textValue = 'unknown';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //  localizationsDelegates: [
      //           AppLocalizations.delegate,
      //           GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      //           GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      //         ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 1,
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          appBar: new PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(150.0),
            child: new AppBar(
              centerTitle: false,
              title: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.0,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "8956",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/rewahub_icon.png',
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "RS 434.25",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient:grad),
              ),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    child: new Text(

                       AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('tabvouchers'),
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .body1
                          .apply(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: new Text(

                     AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('tabpaynow'),
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .body1
                          .apply(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: new Text(

                   AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('tabpoints'),
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .body1
                          .apply(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //body: TabBody(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  }
```

I use this line of code to translate a key to a localized string:
`AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('settingsprofile')`

This works great in all the other screens of my app except this one. Does anyone know why it's not working and how to solve it?

Some things I already tried:

pass the context of the main screen (the screen that holds all the TabBarViews)

wrap every ListTile in a Builder

Comment: You say works great in other screens, then we need widget tree. Can you share widget code which tabBarView is in view?

Comment: why are you commenting the `localizationDelegates`?

Comment: Its defined in the main.dart